# H2 Not dropping sequences for temporary tables

Tags: java, sql, h2

I have an application, where i use H2 temporary table to store large cache. But when i close all connections and shutdown database the sequence for my table not dropped. After a while i have so many leaked sequences with random names.

Questions:

- It is by design to not drop sequences for temp tables?
- How can i figure out that concrete sequence is not used by any table so i can drop that sequence?

Here is simple junit4 test:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.*;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class H2Test {
  String databaseUrl = "jdbc:h2:./SST;";
  String userName = "sa";
  String password = "";
  @Test
  public void tempTableTest() throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    File databaseFile = new File("./SST.mv.db");
    if(databaseFile.exists()){
      databaseFile.delete();
    }

    assertCount("SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES", 0);
    assertCount("SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name = 'SST'", 0);

    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl, userName, password)) {
      execute(connection, "CREATE CACHED LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE SST ( id BIGINT IDENTITY, value VARCHAR(2048) NULL)");
      execute(connection, "INSERT INTO sst(value) VALUES('some value')");
      execute(connection, "SHUTDOWN");
    }

    assertCount("SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name = 'SST'", 0);
    assertCount("SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES", 0);
  }

  private void assertCount(String query, int count) throws SQLException {
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl, userName, password) ) {
      try (Statement st = connection.createStatement()) {
        ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery(query);
        resultSet.next();
        assertEquals(count, resultSet.getInt(1));
        execute(connection, "SHUTDOWN");
      }
    }
  }

  public void execute(Connection connection, String statement) throws SQLException {
    try (Statement st = connection.createStatement()) {
      st.execute(statement);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the H2 database. It will be fixed in H2 version 1.4.180. Sequences of temporary tables are not supposed to be stored in the database file. And they are actually not stored, until they are first used (as part of the `insert` statement in your case).

If you want to remove the sequence manually, you could check whether it is referenced in any of the tables. One way to do that is to run the `script nodata` statement, and check (via regular expression matching) whether a sequence is referenced or not.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. I will see what another options i can use. Parsing script nodata output for me is an overkill. Maybe i can generate primary key manually...